# Why this file "ProjectName_TemporaryKey.pfx" gets created in my project?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Why does the file "ProjectName_TemporaryKey.pfx" get created in project?
And what is its use in the project? I have EDM in my project and some forms, etc.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a file used for code signing:

> Assembly signing (also called strong-name signing) gives an
>   application or component a unique identity that other software can use
>   to identify and refer explicitly to it. A strong name consists of its
>   simple text name, version number, culture information (if provided),
>   plus a public/private key pair. This information is stored in a key
>   file; this can be a Personal Information Exchange (PFX) file or a
>   certificate from the current user's Windows certificate store

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247123%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is a bit more info.

Comment: Your answer was helpful.

Comment: But when I tried creating new pfx with password. It gives me an error.

    Error 3 Unable to copy file "obj\x86\Debug\Utility 1.0.exe" to "bin\Debug\Utility 1.0.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\Utility 1.0.exe' because it is being used by another process. Eduron.Utilities

Comment: To your surprise, it builds in release mode. Would u be more kind to answer this query of mine. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You must be having click once based deployment.Such click once apps needs to be signed digitally by a certificate.If you dont have a certificate of your own  the publishing system will create one for you. you can also take a look at [this](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172240%28vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Your answer helped a lot to understand what this file is meant for. Expected more precise answer which was being told by @Dimitar Dimitrov in his answer.

Comment: I believe your link is no longer valid: " this"